# How can I move a file to other directory using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript. I need to move a file to another directory using JavaScript. How can simply move that file with JavaScript?

How can I solve this?

I tried this, but it didn't work....

```
<html>
<h2>Move file in JavaScript</h2>
<script language="javascript">
function moveFile(){
        var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var file = object.GetFile("Table1.xml");
        file.Move("./Docus/");
        document.write("File is moved successfully");
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="Button" value="Move File" onClick='moveFile()'>
</form>
</html>
```

How can I do this, anyone?

Comment: I sure hope you can't do that. This seems like a **huge** security problem... Also, you do realize that this could only ever work in IE, right?

Comment: @tjameson oh k, How can I solve this problem?.... any idea if?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need to move files on the client's computer?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to run something in a browser, and rename a file on the client's computer?

Comment: You should NOT solve this problem via client-side code, unless you want your system blown to pieces one day by a kid having fun or an aged hacker

Comment: is it possible or not? any other way for this question?

Comment: @user1811486: No.  Not via the web, anyway.  There are like a dozen different things in place to *prevent* a web site accessing local files, and many browsers don't have IE's level of ActiveX support anyway.

Comment: Thank to all for this discussion....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried this code, working perfectly :

```
function moveFile(){
   var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   var file = object.GetFile("C:\\wamp\\www\\phptest.php");
   file.Move("C:\\wamp\\");
   document.write("File is moved successfully");
}
```

In your code, issue seems to be in file path "./Docus/".
Try to put absolute path and then check.

Comment: right it work perfectly? but it didn't work "Error:Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined" in chrome, firefox..

Comment: ActiveX works only under IE browsers (Active Scripting). If you want to make it work under Chrome and Firefox, you should refer these links: [ActiveX in Chrome](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?227645-Please-help-with-AcriveXObject-error) and [ActiveX in FF](https://code.google.com/p/ff-activex-host/)

Comment: I could not run this code even in Edge : "Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined" I want such a code to move a .txt file in local to use in my app.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the problem which you're trying to solve is to create some kind of rich UI (user interface), where user can drag-and-drop files through directory tree.

Well that's is surely possible, but the way to make it right - and with that I mean make it cross-browser compatible and secure - is with a serverside script (PHP, ASP.Net, whatever) running behind it, providing all the data and file-system operations, with a security layer on top of it.

And if you want an unsecure, MS Internet Explorer only solution - sure you can use ActiveX objects.