# How to move a file (picture, movie or audio) to another folder in the same drive?

Tags: android, ios, file-io, windows-8, tablet

I'm new in creating webapp. How would I move file (video, audio or graphic) to another folder in the same drive in the tablet, when user click on the Add attachment button. what is the code for it? Does anyone know?

```
<div>
    <label for="Attachment" id="bodyText">Attachment:</label>
    <input id="Attachment" name="Attachment" type="file" value="" data-theme="c"></input>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="AddAttachment" data-role="button" data-icon="add" data-theme="a" onClick="MoveAttData();"><div id="buttonText">Add Attachment</div></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of: [how to move a file to other directory in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586382/how-to-move-a-file-to-other-directory-in-javascript)

Due to browser file access permissions I would say that in a pure JS, browser environment this isn't possible as you can not write to the File System. The other post was using ActiveX scripting (MS / IE only).

It may also be possible with Flash, but on a tablet environment thats not going to work on iOS even if it is possible.

Comment: I could not use flash. Any possible way to copy the same attachment to another folder? As I need to launch the file when user click on retrieve the file in the future.