# how can i save images in local path where i want when i save the images from website using by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, path

i am junho
I'm wondering how can i change the path when i save the images from website using js
please give me advice to solve this problem.

here is my code

```
(function(){
  var video = document.getElementById('video'),
      photo = document.getElementById('photo'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;


  navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia;

  navigator.getMedia({
      video:true,
      audio:false
  }, function(stream){
      video.srcObject=stream;
      video.play();
  }, function(error){

  });



  document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click', function(){
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 400, 300);
      photo.setAttribute('src', canvas.toDataURL('C:/django/blog/static/img/png'))

      console.log(canvas);
      saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'file-name.png')
  });
})();

function saveAs(uri, filename){
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    if (typeof link.download === 'string'){
        link.href = uri;
        link.download = filename;

        document.body.appendChild(link);

        link.click();

        document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
      window.open(uri);
    }

};
```

i want to save the path to C:\django\blog\static\img\before_detection in my local

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move a file to other directory using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586382/how-can-i-move-a-file-to-other-directory-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, `canvas.toDataURL()` does not expect a local filesystem path to be passed as parameter.

> i want to save the path to C:\django\blog\static\img\before_detection
>   in my local

At Chromium/Chrome navigate to `chrome://settings`, select `Advanced`, scroll to `Downloads`, select `Ask where to save each file before downloading`, which will prompt user to accept file and provide a means for user to select which directory the file will be saved in at the OS's file manager application window, if `Save` is clicked.

Comment: @원준호 Alternatively you can create a Chrome packaged app, see [JavaScript/Ajax Write to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460493/javascript-ajax-write-to-file)

Comment: yes i understand. i reset my settings. but it is not the exact result i want.but for now it is helpful for me thank you!

Comment: @원준호 You can alternatively set the default download directory to the path "C:\django\blog\static\img\before_detection"