# Locally save a pdf in the folder I want with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a user who will insert a pdf in my web application with:

```
<input type="submit" id="pdf" class="btn" value="Add" name="btnAdd" onclick="savePdf()">
```

And I would like to get this file in my javascript function and save it in a folder of my project.

My function :

```
function savePdf(){
        var pdf = document.getElementById("pdf");
        if(pdf.files.length != 0){
                    var file = pdf.files;
        }
}
```

Think I have the right solution to recover the file but I have no idea how to save it to the folder I want. Hope you can redirect me to the functions that I have used thanks.

Comment: Assuming you mean client-side JavaScript, you can't do it in JS alone. You'll need to submit it to a server-side script over AJAX (for example), and have the server-side code save it to the folder.

Comment: Do you think I should send the file as a parameter to a php function from ajax which will save it in my folder?

Comment: Try to refer this question answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586382/how-can-i-move-a-file-to-other-directory-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to find the answer, I was forced to use ajax to accomplish this task.

Retrieving the pdf in the input:

```
var files = document.getElementById("pdf").files;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", files[0]);
```

Calls the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "ajaxfile.php",
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   data: formData
}).then(function(response){
   console.log(response);
});
```

"processData" and "contentType" is essential for the proper functioning of sending the file.

My Php code (ajaxfile.php) :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    // file name
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    // Location
    $location = '../pdf/'.$filename;

    $response = 0;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$location)){
        $response = 1;
    }   
    echo $response;
}
```